# SAS store values temporary arrays

Tags: arrays, sas

I want to store values of ID in array when status is PROBATION.
After that, I want to look up in the table the field ID that are in array to create a new record of them With the status changed (I want to maintain the original and the new record)

````
data have;
  input agreement  $10.      id         status$15.    ;
datalines;
0002255                         1       PROBATION   
0002255                         2       NORMAL      
0007777                         3       NORMAL    
0007777                         4       NORMAL    
0007777                         5       NORMAL      
0008888                         6       PROBATION   
0008888                         7       NORMAL      
0008888                         8       NORMAL      
run;

data want (drop=i);
  set have;
 /* by agreement;*/
  output;
  j=0;
  i=0;
  retain j;
  retain i;
  array ids [1000] _temporary_;
  array var {1} id ;
 

  if status='PROBATION' then
    do;
    i + 1;
    ids{i}=id;
    %put ids{i};
  end;
 
  
  if id=ids{j} then
    do;
    j+1;
    status='OTHER';
    output;
    end;
run;
```

What I have

    agreement   id  status      day
      0002255    0  NORMAL       3
      0002255    1  PROBATION    4
      0002255    2  NORMAL      14
      0007777    3  NORMAL      23
      0007777    4  NORMAL       8
      0007777    5  NORMAL       9
      0008888    6  PROBATION   11
      0008888    7  NORMAL      12
      0008888    8  NORMAL       5

What I  Want

    agreement   id  status      day
      0002255    0  NORMAL       3
      0002255    1  OTHER        3
      0002255    1  PROBATION    4
      0002255    2  NORMAL      14
      0007777    3  NORMAL      23
      0007777    4  NORMAL       8
      0007777    5  NORMAL       9
      0007777    5  OTHER        9
      0008888    6  PROBATION   11
      0008888    7  NORMAL      12
      0008888    8  NORMAL       5
      0008888    8  NORMAL
````

Comment: What does your desired output look like from this example data?

Comment: `%put ids{i};`  is not right, you may wanna `put ids{i}=;`

Comment: The data you say you have is different in de program and in the picture _(which I converted to text)_ under it. Also, I suspect you made a mistake in the data you want, because you duplicate a line for id 5, while PROBATION occurs on a line with id 6 and I have no idea why you duplicated a line with id 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
 input agreement $ id status $10. day;
datalines;
0002255 0 NORMAL    3  
0002255 1 PROBATION 4  
0002255 2 NORMAL    14 
0007777 3 NORMAL    23 
0007777 4 NORMAL    8  
0007777 5 NORMAL    9  
0008888 6 PROBATION 11 
0008888 7 NORMAL    12 
0008888 8 NORMAL    5  
;

data want(drop=d dd);
   set have;

   if status ne "PROBATION" then d = day;

   else do;
      status = "OTHER";
      dd = day;
      day = d;
      output;
      status = "PROBATION";
      day = dd;
   end;

   output;
   retain d;
run;
```